# Missing System.Windows.Interactivity in Silverlight 4 - mvvm light tutorial

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light

I'm trying to follow this [MVVM Light Toolkit V3 Alpha 2: EventToCommand behavior](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/11/05/mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha-2-eventtocommand-behavior.aspx) tutorial.

I'm using vs2010 with silverlight 4. I dont have expression blend.

The tutorial states that

> In addition, you need the System.Windows.Interactivity.dll

I don't seem to have this: I can't see this when I try to add a reference.
Anyone know how I should get / add it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just noticed that the dll is included the download zip from the tutorial.

Comment: If someone else is looking for these dlls and doesn't have Blend installed, there is a free SDK download:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=d197f51a-de07-4edf-9cba-1f1b4a22110d

Answer (score 19):

Usually it is located here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend 3\Interactivity\Libraries\Silverlight\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll

But if you don't have expression blend then...

As @Dan Auclair points out, you can download the SDK and gain access to these dll. Download from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=d197f51a-de07-4edf-9cba-1f1b4a22110d

Answer (score 4):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=D197F51A-DE07-4EDF-9CBA-1F1B4A22110D

download and install this SDK, then you can find this dll in the folder

Answer (score 1):

**For Silverlight 5** *Version: 5.0.5.0 runtime Version: v4.0.30319*

I needed the System.Windows.Interactivity.dll available from this install http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=9503

It lets you choose where to install it but once it had finished it came up in the .NET tab under Add References...

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just install a 60 days evaluation of blend 4. Nice to use when you are using MVVM  light.